# How many difficulty levels are there in New Game Plus?

Tags: deus-ex-the-fall

For Deus Ex: The Fall on iOS starting a New Game Plus will start over but on a harder difficulty.  How many difficulty levels are there?  i.e. how many times till the game doesn't get any harder when start on New Game+?